# Removing text input boxes with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

Please take a look at this

http://jsfiddle.net/tt13/CFbpt/

What I need is,

1. When user clicks + button, to add new text input
2. Hide + button from first text box when text boxes count reaches 3 (user can add max 2 text boxes) and unhide when textbox count < 3
3. Remove parent text box (which located to the left from button) when user clicks x button

My + button works well: it adss textboxes on the fly. But x (remove) buttons doesn't. WHat am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the indication is that you are currently setting you're delete event before the button actuaclly exists. Instead put the delete handler inside the add button event:

http://jsfiddle.net/CFbpt/1/

But really you should be putting your code into the question so that other people can find it...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var addCvBtn    = $(".addCvBtn"),
    rmCvBtn    = $(".rmCvBtn"),
    rcmText     = $(".rcmText"),
    btncount    = 0,
    inputhtml = '<div class="cvInputContainer withRemBtn"><input placeholder="CV Linkini daxil edin" name="cvlinks[]" type="text" /><button class="btn btn-medium btn-danger rmCvBtn " type="button"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></button></div>';

addCvBtn.click(function(){
        if(btncount == 3)  addCvBtn.hide();
        else
        {
            $(this).parent().parent().append(inputhtml);
            btncount++;
            rmCvBtn    = $(".rmCvBtn");
            $(".withRemBtn").on('click', ".rmCvBtn", function(){
               addCvBtn.show();
               $(this).parent().remove(); //EDITED
               btncount--;
               alert('deleted');
            });
        }        
    });



 });
```

EDIT: The more dynamic use of .on() which I think you might have been trying to achieve is:
$(document).ready(function(){

```
    var addCvBtn    = $(".addCvBtn"),
    rmCvBtn    = $(".rmCvBtn"),
    rcmText     = $(".rcmText"),
    btncount    = 0,
    inputhtml = '<div class="cvInputContainer withRemBtn"><input placeholder="CV Linkini daxil edin" name="cvlinks[]" type="text" /><button class="btn btn-medium btn-danger rmCvBtn " type="button"><i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i></button></div>';

addCvBtn.click(function(){
        if(btncount == 3)  addCvBtn.hide();
        else
        {
            $(this).parent().parent().append(inputhtml);
            btncount++;
            rmCvBtn    = $(".rmCvBtn");
        }        
    });


 $(document).on('click', ".withRemBtn .rmCvBtn", function(){
               addCvBtn.show();
               $(this).parent().remove(); //EDITED
               btncount--;
               alert('deleted');
            });  
 });
```

Comment: It removes button not textbox

Comment: so you just go $(this).parent().remove(); you can adjust the rest to your needs.

Comment: Can you please edit jsFiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CFbpt/3/ - but make sure the full question and answer is here as well...

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare you `delete` event in `click`. In you code you at first set delete event and after that you added it. It will not work, because btn delete does not exit on step adding  'enter code heredelete' event